# Delete the automatic popover shown on Gtk Entry

Tags: c++, gtk, popover

I recently migrated my source code to Gtkmm 3.20. In this versión of gtk  appears an automatic popover.

How I can remove this functionality? See image.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a touchscreen?

Comment: Yes, I use touchscreen.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature of GTK+ 3.20: if the GtkEntry sees touch events, which happens if you use a touchscreen and tap the entry, then it will automatically show that popover, which contains touch-friendly editing buttons (Paste is what you see there; I presume Cut, Copy, and Select All would be available on a non-password GtkEntry as well).

There is no way to turn that off, however it should only show up when you touch the GtkEntry; if you use keyboard or mouse navigation, it shouldn't show up. If it still does, you can report that as a bug to the GNOME Bugzilla.

It seems you are implementing a PIN entry field. I agree that in that case the popover isn't needed. You should state that case directly to the GTK+ developers then; maybe they will provide an API to turn the popover off (but it will not be part of GTK+ 3.20).